# Javascript a var in closure always contain the same element?

Tags: javascript, closures

See the fiddle here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/opwxLm5d/)

```
var combine = function(n, k) {

    function backtracking(n, k) {
        if(k){  // min(k)=1, when k=0 break
            for(var i=1; i<=n; ++i){
                if(!used[i]){
                    used[i] = true;
                    solution[k-1] = i;  // solution.length=k
                    // console.log(solution.length);
                    arguments.callee(n, k-1);
                    used[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            console.log(solution);
            return result.push(solution);    // ?
        }
    }

    var used = [],
        result = [],
        solution = [];
    if(k>n){
        return [];
    }else{
        backtracking(n, k);
    }

    return result;
};

var b = combine(4, 2);
console.log(b);
```

why the result array always contain the same element>I mean it should have the same value like the array solution?

b output:

```
[[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
```

I expected this:

```
[[2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [4, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [4, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

I guess it's a closure problem .but how could I do this???

I try to make the `result[]` as a global var.but still not work..

I see that post. but it's closure within a loop. but this is not caused by loop problem .loop actually works fine.It's a recursive problem within a closure..

Comment: Can include `js` from https://jsfiddle.net/opwxLm5d/  at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 code added..

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
  return result.push(solution);
```

You're still using the same Array object again, any later change to that object will be persisted on the result.
You need to make a clone of the solution object each time you push it to result:

```
  return result.push(solution.slice(0));
```

Here is the new Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70oto3kr/).